# location_id for Facebook event creation

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

I am trying to use `location_id` , which I retrieved from my current location, as a parameter for Facebook event creation, here is my code:

I have set up all the authorization token and extended permission , and it indeed returned a valid location id; however, after I plug the `location_id` into the event creation parameter array, it did not create an event. (all the other fields are set through a form).Could anyone help?

Here is my code:

```cs
  try{
    //default location
    $event_url =  $my_url . 'create_group.php';
    $event_location = $facebook->api('/me?fields=location');
    $event_location_id = $event_location['id'];
    echo $event_location_id;
   }

   catch(Exception $e)
   {
   echo $e;
   }



$params= array(

    "name" => "[Study Group]".$_POST['name'],
    "description" => $_POST['description'],
    "location_id" => $event_location_id,
    "start_time" => $_POST['start_time'].$_POST['time_zone'],
    "privacy_type" => $_POST['privacy_type'],
    "end_time" => $_POST['end_time'].$_POST['time_zone']
);
```

Here is the exception I have:

```
Exception: The place or event you attempted to plan to attend is invalid. Please try a different place or event.
```

The exception is solved in the following way: 
change:

```
$event_location_id = $event_location['id'];
```

to

```
$event_location_id= $event_location['location']['id'];
```

Comment: You getting any errors? Also please add the code of event publishing in your question

Comment: I have added the exception I got

Comment: Please add your code for posting the event.

Comment: thanks for the help.I just solved it by checking the exception as you suggested. the location_id should be returned as $event_location['location']['id'].

Comment: It would be nice if you could add the same in answer and accept it, so people in future might get the answer for same problem as yours

Answer (score 0):

The exception tells itself that the error is the wrong value of Location Id. 
And as you have debugged it by yourself that this was because of you retrieved it as

```
$event_location_id = $event_location['id'];
```

Which should instead be retrieved as

```
$event_location_id= $event_location['location']['id'];
```